# Release of multiple projects with maven

Tags: automation, hudson, maven, build-automation, release

We got common component C and 2 projects A & B. Each project depends on component C.

The problem is that version of C after release is 1.0 but A & B are still referring to version  1.0-SNAPSHOT of C.

Is there a way to configure Hudson to release C, update POM for projects A and B and then to do a release of these projects automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven-versions-plugin can be asked to update the dependency version. It's up to you to write <del>hudson</del> jenkins jobs to run it.

Comment: Yes, use the maven-versions-plugin.  If you aren't comfortable with having your CI server actually modify your pom file for you, at least have it report in a separate build that updates are available to you.  This is something you should do periodically yourself as well.